# Microsoft Office 2007 in Wine will not check Spelling & Grammar in Portuguese

Tags: 10.10, microsoft-office, playonlinux, language-support, spell-checking

I'm using Microsoft Office 2007 installed with PlayOnLinux (Wine), it's working all fine, except that it will not check Spelling & Grammar in Portuguese (Brazil).

The spelling check in English occurs perfectly. In Portuguese it says that all is right, even when it's not. It's like it just accept everything I write as correct.

Any idea how to solve this? Does Wine support the MS Office's spelling check feature at all?

**--update:**

Just realized that the Spelling Check also is not working on Libre Office for my language (Portuguese, Brazil), maybe the problem is bigger then I thought.

Comment: Why not use libre office?

Comment: @"Tom Brito" - have Clicked on Word Options - Proofing - Dictionary language and chosen the correct language?

Comment: @user606723 As this can go really far, I think it would be better to start another thread on this. You may ask here in the site "why one prefers MS Office to Libre Office?", and I can put my answers there.

Comment: @fossfreedom Yes.

Comment: I use Microsoft Office at work and I am well aware that it is a superior product. I did not want to talk about that However, libre office works almost as well for 95% of use. I guess the question I had was.. have you tried using libre office and are you sure it won't be good enough for your use?

Comment: @user606723 Oh, sorry. Yes, I did. I'm moving just now from Libre Office.

Comment: @tom - maybe because you need to install the optional proofing tools?  See this technet article - I know it is for office 2010, but it might give you some ideas. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162397.aspx

Comment: @fossfreedom thanks for the hint. I will read it and I tell here my progress.

Comment: [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179145(office.12).aspx#BKMK_IdentifyInstalledLanguages) item shows how to identify installed languages, but I have no "Office" directory inside the registry `HKCU\Software\Microsoft`. Also I found no "LanguageResources" doing a search in regedit.

Comment: As opinions are putting here, maybe someone who visit here would like to know that for some people like me Libreoffice is a superior product compared with Microsoft's.

Comment: @tom-brito I have edited my answer to include office 2007. You may need to approve the edits before you will be able to see them.

Comment: this question is strictly MSOffice nothing to do with Wine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Open office for this answer. I believe Libra Office is not that much different in regards to how language functionality works.

- Open the tools menu in office navigate to options

[image: Tools Options]

- Select Language settings
- then Languages

[image: Language settings]

- Here you can see select which language you want to set as the defautl language for you documents. Notice the ABC with the blue tick that idicates a language with spell checking capabilities.

[image: select the language]

- If your language comes up with out the ABC blue tick spell check support you will need to install the additional language packs.

[image]

> $ sudo apt-get install "(myspell|libreoffice).*-pt-br$"

That should install all the language packs for libreoffice that you need. As well as the spell checker which is myspell. 
If you want to check what will be installed as a -s to apt-get to check. -s will just show you what would have been done with out actually doing any thing.

> $ apt-get -s install "(myspell|libreoffice).*-pt-br$"

As for micro-soft office it also needs to have the additional language packs installed.

**In ms-office 2007 you need do the following**

- Click the office button (the wheel thing in the top left corner)
- Click the Word options button on the bottom right of the menu.
- Select the popular options on the left.
- then click the language settings button near the bottom of the screen on the left pane.
- Select your language in the right pane under "Avalible editing languages"
- click the add button in the middle to add it to the "Enabled editing languages"
- Then select it as the "Primary editing language" from the drop down bellow.
- Office 2007 will now use that as your language
- You may need to install additional languages as part of your office installation process. As it defaults to English.

.

Comment: Libre Office is working, it's enough for now. For the MS Office I will need to re-install and install the "profiting tools". Thanks!